# Make PL/SQL code robust

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want make PL/SQL code more robust and independent of any change in the values that I am passing now. For calculation, I am reading some values from the table ,also have hardcoded some values in the pl/SQL code, e.g., `act_type='Savings'` and `sqn_no=109`.

I want to get rid of this hardcoded values so that I can dynamically pass all those values. This will help me to in 2 ways:

1. If there is any change then no need to update my code, for example, suppose I got another account type `act_type='Savings'` or `='checkin'` then my new design should take care of this without any code change, and
2. It will be easy for user implementation.

I am planning to introduce new table somewhere to store all those values and will update the table when there is a change in the values but not sure from where to start.

Any help in designing this process would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

prepare some config table and store te configuration within.

for eg.

```
create table cfg (name varchar2(10), cfg_cal varchar2(20));

insert into cfg values ('act_type_v','Savings');

commit;
```

and in the procedure you read from that table into variable:

```
declare
act_type varchar2(10);
[...]

SELECT cfg_cal
INTO act_type
FROM cfg 
WHERE name ='act_type_v';
[...]
```